# image max-height & overflow hidden with 100% width

Tags: html, css, image

How can I make my post's featured image fix at height 220px crop top and bottom off? I find it highly repetitive with the image below this... a cropped version would do a nicer job. I tried to hide it but it seems like its the same image as my featured image siting at thesuit.sg/blog so i can't use:

```
display:none;
```

This is a sample page: http://thesuit.sg/2014/05/infographic-data-never-sleeps/

when i tried to do it, the height didn't resize proportionately.

What i used was:

```
max-height: 220px;
height: auto; /* for IE 8 */
overflow: hidden;
```

Comment: You are using wordpress right? Why not use wordpress's built in functionality to generate thumbnails your desired maximum height when uploading and use that.

Comment: You can set the image as a background-image and then use background-size: cover; to clip the image. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size

Comment: I hate broken links...